# OWL object property bidirectionel

Tags: owl, bidirectional, object-property

I need to say that an object property is bidirectionnel. I know that we can use the inverseOf attribute to link 2 property but is it possible to say that the inverseOf an objectProperty is himself?

```
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/ont.owl#isLinkedTo">
    <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/ont.owl#isLinkedTo"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>
```

Or I have to do so :

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="http://micorr.ig.he-arc.ch/vocab#artefacts_alloy">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/ont.owl#isLinkedTo"/>
            <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://micorr.ig.he-arc.ch/vocab#artefacts_metal"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
</owl:Class>

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://micorr.ig.he-arc.ch/vocab#artefacts_metal">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/ont.owl#isLinkedTo"/>
            <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://micorr.ig.he-arc.ch/vocab#artefacts_alloy"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
</owl:Class>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why should it not be possible? And have you ever heard about [*reflexivity*](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-primer/#Property_Characteristics)?

Comment: By the way, what's the reason for the `sparql` tag? And why no `owl` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed make a property the inverse of itself, that's fine. However, a more explicit way of expressing that a relation is bidirectional is by defining the property being *symmetrical*:

```
<owl:SymmetricProperty rdf:about="http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/ont.owl#isLinkedTo"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what i was looking for.